# how to retrieve password from within hook_user_presave()

Tags: hooks, users

I am trying to catch the inputed password on the user registration page from within the hook_user_presave(). I want to send this password out to an external database for storage. However, when I analyzed the $edit variable, I found that the password field was returning an encrypted password.

Is there any way for me to retrieve the actual password?

Comment: IMHO, site admins *should* not have access to user's passwords in unencrypted form.  I can see no use-case that cannot be covered by you saving the *encrypted password* in the external database.

Comment: the client has an external database which it wants to be totally synced with the drupal database, this is the use case.

Comment: @user1015214 In that case some sort of replication at the database level might be more appropriate than pushing raw password data around. Just to clear something up here: User passwords are not encrypted, they're one-way hashed with a salt (SHA512 in the default implementation).

Comment: I'm not very knowledged about encryptions and hashs and don't know the difference between them. But I will see if I can do something on the database level. Did you have any ideas? Normally I pass the data via an api with php script, can I do something similar on the database level?

Comment: @user1015214 Encryption = 2-way, Hash = 1-way. So once you have the hashed password there's no going back (well, short of rainbow tables but that's another story). If you plan to use the same password as part of a login mechanism on the other site, you'll need to reproduce Drupal's hashing functionality there too, and copy both the hash and salt across. That's still not ideal as you're passing the hash and salt around together, which makes cracking a lot easier (still computationally expensive, though). The password stuff is in includes/password.inc, that might be the best place to start

Comment: @arpitr Passwords are not encrypted; see Clive's comment.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yeah, I got it :)

Comment: If the client wants the external database to be totally synced with the Drupal database, then it makes absolutely no sense to save the password in clear text.  The passwords should be save in the same format as in the Drupal database (i.e. as one-way  hashes).  (PS: My apologies for using the word "encrypted".  Clive is of course right, they're hashed, not encrypted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It us not advised not to use the user's password as a raw value, however if you still want to access the password field value in unencrypted form than try the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 * Alters user_register_form.
 */
function MyModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add the additional validation callback for the user registration form.
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MyModule_user_register_form_validate';
  }
}

// Callback function for Validation handler of user_register_form.
function MyModule_user_register_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['pass'])) {
    // Here you will get the value of password.
    $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You may try the `md5` encryption, every time it will give same result. Few links for easy reference: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/26.html , http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/

Comment: It's not encryption!! Sorry, but it's worth making this point - MD5/SHA/etc are hashing algorithms, not encryption algorithms :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to modify the form and add another submit handler then use that. Once it's in Drupal it's 100% encrypted.

**BUT... you SHOULD NOT be sending peoples passwords to an external database in raw form. You should send the encrypted password if anything.**